# Stuck at understanding how duplicate prevention formula works in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Many blog posts and educational sites tell us to use `=countif($A$2:A2,A2)=1` in the selected range.

However, they don't explain it. And for me it doesn't work and since I can't understand it I can't debug it.

My understanding about Sheets is that `$` is for absolute reference. Thus `$A$2` means an absolute reference to the `A2` cell. For me the formula becomes `A2:A2` which is weird.

Can anyone please explain how this formula prevents the duplicates and what is the logic behind it? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The range reference `$A$2:A2` is using a mixed address mode where `$A$2` is absolute and `A2` is relative. When the formula is "dragged down" by copy-pasting cells or applying it to a range in a [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) custom formula rule, the first part stays put and the second part adjusts, like this:

`=countif($A$2:A2, A2) = 1`

`=countif($A$2:A3, A3) = 1`

`=countif($A$2:A4, A4) = 1`

...and so on.

`countif()` will thus get the number of values that match the value in the current row, looking at the range that starts in `A2` and ends in the current row of column A. If that count is `1`, the formula gets `true`. If there are more than one copy of the value in the rows above and including the current row, the formula gets `false`.

See [absolute and relative references](https://edu.gcfglobal.org/en/googlespreadsheets/types-of-cell-references/1/).